# Does any one know how to make the animation work?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been having some problems with animating my 2D player to simply play a short animation when the left arrow key is pressed and the same with the right arrow key, after the the keys are pressed I want it to go back to the idle animation. I have 3 bool parameters, Isleft, Isright, Isidle. I have been struggling with this for a few days now and was wondering if anyone knows how to actually make this work.

I have been trying everything by trial and error changing the code and changing the conditions in the animator window

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public GameObject character;

    private Animator anim;
    private Scene scene;

    

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

        }
        
        else
        {

        }
        

    }


    /*void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        switch (collision.gameObject.tag)
        {
            case "Enemy":
                Destroy(gameObject);
                break;
            default:
                //nothing
                break;     
        }
    }*/

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
    }


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKey)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }
        // Move Right
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool("Isright", true);
        }
        //Move Left
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)))
        {
            transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime;
            anim.SetBool("Isleft", true);          
        }
        else 
        {
            anim.SetBool("Isidle", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you ever set these booleans to false?

Comment: I haven't set any to false and I don't know which bools to set false.

Comment: Then your question is effectively the same as "I always turn light switches on but never turn any off. Why is there more than one light on in my house?".

Comment: I just don't know which ones need to be false.

Comment: Never mind thanks to your comment about light switches it helped me figure it out and now I have got the animation to work how I want it. So thank you my good sir.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set booleans to false and this last "else" block refers to LeftArrow/A. If you are not holding either of them, Isidle is true.